# TYPO3 all pages return page not found errors except the Home page

Tags: typo3

I have installed TYPO3 9.5.27 Locally.

All pages Except the Root Page showing the following error
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hewCr.png)

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at t3v9.local Port 80
```

Why this is happening? Anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check, that your apache has enabled `mod_rewrite` and that the TYPO3 default `.htaccess` file (see `typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess` for recommended example) is located in the document root.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

.htaccess file is there.
Also enabled mod_rewrite through the command: a2enmod rewrite

But still the issue is there. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you restart apache webserver after `a2enmod rewrite`? This is required in order to load new enabled modules.

Comment: Yes tried. But no result. but I solved it by manually changing the above-given solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.

Here in `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2` change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#system-requirements-webserver